# Unknown URL getting inserted to email Body in salesforce

Tags: email, salesforce, apex

*"*http://cs23.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=00D190000001brI&esid=01918000000bcHs*"*  gets inserted in email when it is Sent to any user. This URL has no relivience to any image/ doc in my SF org. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: This happens only when I use "mail.setTargetObjectId" but does not happen when I use "mail.setToAddresses"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed. Its due to Activity setting for HTML email history.if this is enabled then SF addes blank image to check if the html email is opened.